# Java ArrayList's first element is always null

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I started to do a homework and I needed to have a list for products but whenever I use add method to add a product to list the first product is always null but second and third doesn't have any problem about that please help me about this problem is so annoying. This code gives an error about the null value becuse actually there should be a product class object in the 0 index of ArrayList but 0 index is always null as I said I couldn't find the reason of this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Assignment01_20210808043 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Store s = new Store("Migros","www.migros.com");

        Customer c = new Customer("CSE 102");
        System.out.println(c);
        
        ClubCustomer cc = new ClubCustomer("Club CSE 102", "0555124567");
        cc.addPoints(20);
        cc.addPoints(30);
        System.out.println(cc.getPhone());
        System.out.println(cc);
        
        
        Product p = new Product("1234", "Computer", 20, 1000.00);
        FoodProduct fp = new FoodProduct("3456", "Snickers", 100, 2, 250, true, true, true, false);
        CleaningProduct cp = new CleaningProduct("5678", "Mop", 28, 99, false, "Multi-room");
        

        s.addProduct(p);
    s.addProduct(fp);
    System.out.println(s.getProductIndex(p));
    System.out.println(s.getProduct(0));
    System.out.println(s.getProductIndex(fp));
    System.out.println(s.getProduct(1));
    s.showList();
        
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.getInventorySize(); i++)
            System.out.println(s.getProduct(i));
        s.addProduct(cp);
        
        s.addProduct(new Product("4321", "iPhone", 50, 99.00));
        
        System.out.println(s.getProductIndex(new FoodProduct("8888", "Apples", 500, 1, 50, false, false, false, false)));
        
        System.out.println(cp.purchase(2));
        if(fp.containsGluten())
            System.out.println("My wife cannot eat or drink " + fp.getName());
        else
            System.out.println("My wife can eat or drink " + fp.getName());
        
        if(fp.containsPeanuts())
            System.out.println("My friend cannot eat or drink " + fp.getName());
        else
            System.out.println("My friend can eat or drink " + fp.getName());
        s.getProduct(0).addToInventory(3);
        Product cur = new Product(null, null, 0, 0);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < s.getInventorySize(); i++)
            cur = s.getProduct(i);
            System.out.println(cur);
            for(int j = i + 1; j < s.getInventorySize(); j++)
                if(cur.equals(s.getProduct(j)))
                    System.out.println(cur.getName() + " is the same price as " + s.getProduct(j).getName());

//      Product c = new Product("25","elma",5,3);
//      Product b = new Product("25","armut",5,3);
//      Product a = new Product("25","ayva",5,3);
//      FoodProduct d = new FoodProduct("25", "portakal", 5, 3, 30, false, false, false, false);
//      System.out.println(c);
//      s.addProduct(a);
//      s.addProduct(b);
//      s.addProduct(c);
//      s.showList();
//      System.out.println(s.getProductIndex(a));
//      System.out.println(s.getProductIndex(b));
//      System.out.println(s.getProductIndex(c));
//      System.out.println(s.getProduct(1).getName());
//      if (a.equals(d)) System.out.println("eşit");
}

}

class Product {
private String id;
private String name;
private int quantity;
private double price;

    public Product(String id, String name, int quantity, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public int remaining() {
        return quantity;
    }
    
    public int addToInventory(int amount) {
        if (amount >= 0) {
            this.quantity += amount;
        }
        return this.quantity;
    }
    
    public double purchase(int amount) {
        if ((amount > this.quantity) || (amount < 0)) return 0;
        else {
            this.quantity -= amount;
            return (amount*this.price);
        }
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Product "+this.name+" has "+this.quantity+" remaining";
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Product product) {
        if (this.price == product.getPrice()) return true;
        return false;
    }

}

class FoodProduct extends Product {
private int calories;
private boolean dairy;
private boolean eggs;
private boolean peanuts;
private boolean gluten;

    public FoodProduct (String id, String name, int quanitity, double price, int calories, boolean dairy, boolean eggs, boolean peanuts, boolean gluten) {
        super(id, name, quanitity, price);
        this.calories = calories;
        this.dairy = dairy;
        this.eggs = eggs;
        this.peanuts = peanuts;
        this.gluten = gluten;
    }
    
    public void setCalories(int calories) {
        this.calories = calories;
    }
    
    public int getCalories() {
        return calories;
    }
    
    public boolean containsDairy() {
        return this.dairy;
    }
    
    public boolean containsEggs() {
        return this.eggs;
    }
    
    public boolean containsPeanuts() {
        return this.peanuts;
    }
    
    public boolean containsGluten() {
        return this.gluten;
    }

}

class CleaningProduct extends Product {
private boolean isLiquid;
private String WhereToUse;

    public CleaningProduct (String id, String name, int quantity, double price, boolean isLiquid, String WhereToUse) {
        super(id, name, quantity, price);
        this.isLiquid = isLiquid;
        this.WhereToUse = WhereToUse;
    }
    
    public void setWhereToUse(String WhereToUse) {
        this.WhereToUse = WhereToUse;
    }
    
    public String getWhereToUse() {
        return this.WhereToUse;
    }
    
    public boolean isLiquid() {
        return this.isLiquid;
    }

}

class Customer {
private String name;

    public Customer (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}

class ClubCustomer extends Customer {
private String phone;
private int points;

    public ClubCustomer (String name, String phone) {
        super(name);
        this.phone = phone;
        this.points = 0;
    }
    
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    
    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }
    
    public int getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }
    
    public void addPoints(int points) {
        if (!(points < 0)) this.points += points;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return this.getName()+" has "+this.points;
    }

}

class Store {
private String name;
private String website;
ArrayList\<Product\> products = new ArrayList\<Product\>();

    public Store(String name, String website) {
        this.name = name;
        this.website = website;
        
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    
    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
    
    public String getWebsite() {
        return this.website;
    }
    
    public void showList() {
        System.out.println(products);
    }
    
    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
    }
    
    public void addProduct(Product product, int index) {
        products.add(index, product);
    }
    
    public Product getProduct(int index) {
        if ((index > 0) && (index < products.size())) return products.get(index);
        return null;
    }
    
    public int getProductIndex(Product product) {
        return products.indexOf(product);
    }
    
    public int getInventorySize() {
        return products.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mind very visibly highlighting where the error occurs? That's alot of code to read through just trying to find the location of the problem.

Comment: @BlueDev I'm pretty sure the OP has NO idea where the  problem actually is, but is getting a `NullPointerException` at `s.getProduct(0).addToInventory(3);` and there initial loop will show the first element as been `null` ... due to how the `getProduct` method works

Answer (score 4):

In `getProduct` you're doing ...

```
if ((index > 0) && (index < products.size())) {
```

BUT, arrays (and `List`/`ArrayList`) are `0` indexed, that is, the first element appears at position `0`.

So, when you ask for the first product (at position `0`), your code goes, "`0` is NOT greater than `0`", so returns `null`

Change it to...

```
if ((index >= 0) && (index < products.size())) {
```

Comment: It solved this problem I didn't realized thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains explicit provisions to NOT return the product at index zero.

```
if ((index > 0) ...
```

You return null instead.

You meant '>= 0'.  But the lesson here is: learn to carefully read the code you wrote.  You explained to us in the quesion that you understood the existence of index 0, but you did not reflect that understanding in your code.

Comment: yes İt worked I didn't realized this thank you.